# exclude weight of free product on cart

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to caltulate the total wight of products in cart and here is my code:

```
//If we have no weight, try to calculate this
            $weight = 0;
            if ($quote->getShippingAddress()->getWeight() == null ||
                $quote->getShippingAddress()->getWeight() == 0 ||
                $quote->getShippingAddress()->getWeight() == ''){

                foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
                    $itemWeight = $item->getWeight();
                    if ($itemWeight != null){
                        $weight += $itemWeight;
                    }
```

Now the problem is I have free/bonus products in the cart and this free product has weight. The above code just add the weight of the free product as well. I want to know is there a way I can exclude the weight of the free product in my cart. Or how can I filter the free/bonus products on magento using the Singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
    $itemWeight = $item->getWeight();
    if ($itemWeight != null && $item->getPrice() != 0){ //if the weight is not null and the price is not 0 (no free product) add the weight to the total.
        $weight += $itemWeight;
    }
....
}
```

Comment: @Sal00m. I added inline comment. Better?

Comment: Great!, +1 for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

According to me u have to fetch free item's sku and made one more condition in foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) that if $item->getsku == in_array(free item sku) then continue; else it adds weight like ur code.

Comment: Dude...don't beg for upvotes. You can ask the OP to accept your answer if it solved his problem, but begging for upvotes is just wrong. read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254562/2047249. the 'Whorish behaviors to avoid' section.